# Using rails-assets-angular gem in mountable Rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to bootstrap AngularJS into a Rails engine using the `rails-assets-angular` gem.

However, when I start the server on the parent app (the app my engine is mounted in), I get this error: `couldn't find file 'angular'`.

---

Here's my **`application.js`**:

```
//= require angular
//= require_tree .
```

Here's my **`.gemspec`**:

```
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)

# Maintain your gem's version:
require "lesson_notes/version"

# Describe your gem and declare its dependencies:
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = "lesson_notes"
  s.version     = LessonNotes::VERSION

  s.files = Dir["{app,config,db,lib}/**/*", "MIT-LICENSE", "Rakefile", "README.rdoc"]

  s.add_dependency "rails",  "~> 4.0.4"
  s.add_dependency "rails-assets-angular"

  s.add_development_dependency "pg"

  s.add_development_dependency "rspec",                     "~> 2.14.1"
  s.add_development_dependency "rspec-rails"
  s.add_development_dependency "capybara",                  "~> 2.2.1"
  s.add_development_dependency "factory_girl_rails",        "~> 4.0"
  s.add_development_dependency "rails-assets-angular-mocks"
  s.add_development_dependency "database_cleaner",          "~> 1.2.0"

  s.test_files = Dir["spec/**/*"]
end
```

And my **`Gemfile`**:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
source "https://rails-assets.org"

gemspec
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out!

In **lib/engine_name/engine.rb** add `require "rails-assets-angular"`.

Comment: Or you can use `require 'bundler/setup'`.